# Best way to query a DictField in MongoEngine

Tags: mongoengine

I've been hunting through the mongoengine documentation and around stack overflow and there doesn't seem to be a very clear answer to this so I'm asking: how do you best query a DictField? 
example code:

```
class Note(Document):
    someData = DictField()

note = Note()
note.someData['someID'] = {"name": "Steve", "age":25}
note.save()
```

The closest I could find in the docs would be:

```
Note.objects(someData__name="Steve")
```

but that hasn't been working
Again, feel like this should be a simple answer.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 16):

You have wrong request, because you miss `someID`.

See you structure in db:

```
>>> db.note.findOne()
>>> {
    "_id": ObjectId("'0'*24")
    "someData": {
        "someID": {
            {"name": "Steve", "age":25}
        }
    }
}
```

So right request will be `Note.objects(someData__someID__name="Steve")`.

Comment: Hi @tbicr how do I query if the Dict is empty or not? Thanks!